# Time based access to samba server

Tags: server, samba, cron

I have a 14.04 server running samba.  I'd like to institute some time based access to the server.  I host media for the whole house, and the goal is for the kids' televisions to become useless at a certain time.  I have placed the following into root's `crontab`:

```
  0 22 *    *   0-4   /etc/init.d/samba stop 
  0 22 *    *   0-4   /etc/init.d/smbd stop 
  0 22 *    *   0-4   /etc/init.d/nmbd stop
```

The shares continue to be active passed the noted time.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your commands are not working because `/etc/init.d/smbd` and `/etc/init.d/nmbd` have the following at the start:

```
if init_is_upstart; then
                        exit 1
                fi
```

So, as the `init` in ubuntu is now Upstart (`/etc/init.d/` is from SysV), you need to run the start-stop scripts from the directory `/etc/init/`. `/etc/init.d/` still exists for backward compatibility because many programs still use this directory.

To make things easier for you, Ubuntu has `service` command:

```
sudo service smbd stop
sudo service nmbd stop
```

While running as `root`:

```
service smbd stop
service nmbd stop
```

`service` will first search in `/etc/init/` directory and then `/etc/init.d/`. `service` is efficient in another sense that if there are two scripts having the same name in those two directories (as in case of `smbd` and `nmbd`) the Upstart script (in `/etc/init/`) will take precedence over SysV script (in `/etc/init.d/`).

Also your `cron` entry can be made simpler:

```
0 22 * * 0-4  service samba stop && service smbd stop && service nmbd stop
```

`&&` ensures that the next command is run only if the previous one is successful (i.e. exit code `$?=0`).

Comment: So the init.d scripts are irrelevant now?  Thanks for the help

Comment: `init.d` scripts are kept for backward compatibility as many programs still use those scripts.